# Read input type hidden value

Tags: php, html, forms

Is it possible to read the value right on load?
I suspect not.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Some test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo sha1("text")?>" >
        </form>
        <?php
        echo $_POST['token'];
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Let's say I want to send some values generated by php like so:

```
<a href="url + page?options=1&token=sasadasdasda878asd7as8d7a">
```

Is there an option to get the token without passing it by URL (using get)?

Comment: No, you can't read `$_POST` until some data is sent to the page. But you could save the value you're outputting in `value=""` to a variable and access it where your 2nd `echo` is.

Comment: No you cant. unless until you submit you can not access value in php

Comment: @HankyPanky i wanna see how it works :D

Comment: why you need it as `$_POST`, you already echoed it as value and you can also use it for further processes in the page!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_POST` will be populated with the data sent by the browser.

If you have a form in the page, then the data submitted by the form will only be sent by the browser *when the browser submits the form*, it won't be submitted when the page is initially loaded since:

- The page will probably be loaded via a GET request, not a POST request
- The browser won't have the data in the form until after it receives the page, so it can't submit that data in the request for the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use $_SESSION, since it's stored on server-side.

Comment: Yes I can use session to store it on server side however how can i compare with the token value in the client side without retrieving the same value to the server to verify it? I guess that's not possible with out GET POST (or REQUEST) which only work by submit or by url or using AJAX. A good example would be welcome.